# Is there a lang-vb or lang-basic option for prettify.js from Google?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, prettify

Visual Basic code does not render correctly with [prettify.js](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-code-prettify) from Google.

on Stack Overflow:

```
Partial Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'set page title
        Page.Title = "Something"
    End Sub

End Class
```

in Visual Studio...

[image: Visual Basic in Visual Studio]

I found this in the [README](https://web.archive.org/web/20160428230325/http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com:80/svn/trunk/README.html) document:

> How do I specify which language my
> code is in?
>
> You don't need to specify the language
> since prettyprint() will guess. You
> can specify a language by specifying
> the language extension along with the
> prettyprint class like so:
>
> ```
> <pre class="prettyprint lang-html">
>   The lang-* class specifies the language file extensions.
>   Supported file extensions include
>     "c", "cc", "cpp", "cs", "cyc", "java", "bsh", "csh", "sh",
>     "cv", "py", "perl", "pl", "pm", "rb", "js",
>     "html", "html", "xhtml", "xml", "xsl".
> </pre>
> ```

I see no *lang-vb* or *lang-basic* option.  Does anyone know if one exists as an add-in?

---

Note: This is related to the [VB.NET code blocks](https://web.archive.org/web/20080914043525/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/general/suggestions/18775) suggestion for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Note: if you need to have syntax highlighting on SO, use `<!-- language: lang-vb -->`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

/EDIT: I've rewritten the whole posting.

Below is a pretty complete solution to the VB highlighting problem. If SO has got nothing better, *please* use it. VB syntax highlighting is definitely wanted.

I've also added a code example with some complex code literals that gets highlighted correctly. However, I haven't even tried to get XLinq right. Might still work, though. The [keywords list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t.aspx) is taken from the MSDN. Contextual keywords are not included. Did you know the `GetXmlNamespace` operator?

The algorithm knows literal type characters. It should also be able to handle identifier type characters but I haven't tested these. Note that the code works on **HTML**. As a consequence, &, < and > are required to be read as named (!) entities, not single characters.

Sorry for the long regex.

```
var highlightVB = function(code) {
    var regex = /("(?:""|[^"])+"c?)|('.*$)|#.+?#|(&amp;[HO])?\d+(\.\d*)?(e[+-]?\d+)?U?([SILDFR%@!#]|&amp;)?|\.\d+[FR!#]?|\s+|\w+|&amp;|&lt;|&gt;|([-+*/\\^$@!#%&<>()\[\]{}.,:=]+)/gi;

    var lines = code.split("\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var line = lines[i];

        var tokens;
        var result = "";

        while (tokens = regex.exec(line)) {
            var tok = getToken(tokens);
            switch (tok.charAt(0)) {
                case '"':
                    if (tok.charAt(tok.length - 1) == "c")
                        result += span("char", tok);
                    else
                        result += span("string", tok);
                    break;
                case "'":
                    result += span("comment", tok);
                    break;
                case '#':
                    result += span("date", tok);
                    break;
                default:
                    var c1 = tok.charAt(0);

                    if (isDigit(c1) ||
                        tok.length > 1 && c1 == '.' && isDigit(tok.charAt(1)) ||
                        tok.length > 5 && (tok.indexOf("&amp;") == 0 &&
                        tok.charAt(5) == 'H' || tok.charAt(5) == 'O')
                    )
                        result += span("number", tok);
                    else if (isKeyword(tok))
                        result += span("keyword", tok);
                    else
                        result += tok;
                    break;
            }
        }

        lines[i] = result;
    }

    return lines.join("\n");
}

var keywords = [
    "addhandler", "addressof", "alias", "and", "andalso", "as", "boolean", "byref",
    "byte", "byval", "call", "case", "catch", "cbool", "cbyte", "cchar", "cdate",
    "cdec", "cdbl", "char", "cint", "class", "clng", "cobj", "const", "continue",
    "csbyte", "cshort", "csng", "cstr", "ctype", "cuint", "culng", "cushort", "date",
    "decimal", "declare", "default", "delegate", "dim", "directcast", "do", "double",
    "each", "else", "elseif", "end", "endif", "enum", "erase", "error", "event",
    "exit", "false", "finally", "for", "friend", "function", "get", "gettype",
    "getxmlnamespace", "global", "gosub", "goto", "handles", "if", "if",
    "implements", "imports", "in", "inherits", "integer", "interface", "is", "isnot",
    "let", "lib", "like", "long", "loop", "me", "mod", "module", "mustinherit",
    "mustoverride", "mybase", "myclass", "namespace", "narrowing", "new", "next",
    "not", "nothing", "notinheritable", "notoverridable", "object", "of", "on",
    "operator", "option", "optional", "or", "orelse", "overloads", "overridable",
    "overrides", "paramarray", "partial", "private", "property", "protected",
    "public", "raiseevent", "readonly", "redim", "rem", "removehandler", "resume",
    "return", "sbyte", "select", "set", "shadows", "shared", "short", "single",
    "static", "step", "stop", "string", "structure", "sub", "synclock", "then",
    "throw", "to", "true", "try", "trycast", "typeof", "variant", "wend", "uinteger",
    "ulong", "ushort", "using", "when", "while", "widening", "with", "withevents",
    "writeonly", "xor", "#const", "#else", "#elseif", "#end", "#if"
]

var isKeyword = function(token) {
    return keywords.indexOf(token.toLowerCase()) != -1;
}

var isDigit = function(c) {
    return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
}

var getToken = function(tokens) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
        if (tokens[i] != undefined)
            return tokens[i];
    return null;
}

var span = function(class, text) {
    return "<span class=\"" + class + "\">" + text + "</span>";
}
```

Code for testing:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'set page title
    Page.Title = "Something"
    Dim r As String = "Say ""Hello"""
    Dim i As Integer = 1234
    Dim d As Double = 1.23
    Dim s As Single = .123F
    Dim l As Long = 123L
    Dim ul As ULong = 123UL
    Dim c As Char = "x"c
    Dim h As Integer = &amp;H0
    Dim t As Date = #5/31/1993 1:15:30 PM#
    Dim f As Single = 1.32e-5F
End Sub
```

Comment: Konrad, this issue is now fixed in Prettify itself, though not implemented on SO.

Comment: @Mark: Yes, I'm aware of this … see the Uservoice discussion. But as you said, SO unfortunately still doesn't implement it, and the Uservoice report has been declined.

Answer (score 2):

Prettify does support VB comments as of the 8th of January 2009.

To get vb syntax highlighting working correctly you need three things;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/External/css/prettify/prettify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/External/css/prettify/lang-vb.js"></script>
```

and a PRE block around your code eg:

```
<PRE class="prettyprint lang-vb">
 Function SomeVB() as string
   ' do stuff
   i = i + 1
 End Function
</PRE>
```

Stackoverflow is missing the lang-vb.js inclusion, and the ability to specify which language via Markdown, ie: `class="prettyprint lang-vb"` which is why it doesn't work here.

for details on the issue: see [the Prettify issues log](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=68)

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, you can put an extra comment character at the end of your comments to get it to look okay.  For example:

```
Sub TestMethod()
    'Method body goes here'
End Sub
```

You also need to escape internal comment characters in the normal vb-fashion:

```
Sub TestMethod2()
    'Here''s another comment'
End Sub
```

Prettify still treats it as a string literal rather than a comment, but at least it looks okay.

Another method I've seen is to start comments with an extra `'//`, like this:

```
Sub TestMethod3()
    ''// one final comment
End Sub
```

Then it's handled like a comment, but you have to deal with C-style comment markers

Comment: Yes, but in that case you could simply use "//".

The reason that people use "''//" is that it looks like a comment AND it compiles in VB as a comment.

Comment: Since we're talking about vb snippets, its probably a good idea to make sure that they will at least compile when copy/pasted into the IDE.